# Let x be an element of finite order n in G. Then show that...

Tags: group-theory

> Prove that if $n$ is odd then $x^i \neq x^{-i}$ for all $i=1,2,3,...,n-1$.

**Attempt**

I tried first using some values of n such as 3 and 5 and 7. I observed that for half(1st half of following set) of the $i$ ($i$ runs from $1,2,3,...,n-1$) i have $x^{2i} \neq e$ beacuse if that would be then that will contradict the fact that order of $x=n$. Also for other half of interval i am trying hard to come up with proof. Can someone suggest some hint

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $x^i=x^{-i}$, this implies that $x^{2i}=1$, thus $n$ divides $2i<2n$, this implies $n=2i$ impossible since $n$ is odd.

Comment: I think you have not read my attempt

Comment: I read your attempt, you don't need to consider only the first half, if you read my proof, I say that if n divides 2i<2n, then 2i=n, you don't need to consider i<n/2.

Comment: The relation $2i<2n$ is true for all $i$. How did you come up with that?

Comment: i=0,...,n-1 implies that i<n which implies 2i<2n

Comment: How does $n|2i$ implies $n=2i$. Cannot we directly say that if n | 2i means n is even

Comment: write the multiples of $n$, a number $c$ divides $n$ means $c=ln$ where $l$ is an integer, so you have, $0,1.n=n,2n,3n,...$, so if $2i<2n$, the only possibility is $2i=n$ assuming that $i\neq 0$.

Comment: Hmm. But why cannot we directly say that if n|2i for all i implies n be even?